# Angular (TypeScript) - How to change the color of text on click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I change the color of text using Angular (TypeScript). I have a button that when clicked it changes the background color of the Header and Main section. But I want that SAME button to also change the color of the text. When I click I want the background, for example, in red and the text in white.

I will add some more information to this question.

**I did something in "data.service.ts" for the same button (that is in main section) to also change the background color in Main section:**

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class DataService {


  private mensagemFonte = new BehaviorSubject <string> ('default value')
  actualMensagem = this.mensagemFonte.asObservable();

  constructor() { }


  alteraMensagem (mensagem: string) {

    this.mensagemFonte.next(mensagem)

  }

}
```

**Then, in "header.component.ts":**

```
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {


  DarkTheme: string;




  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ChangeColor(color: string) {


    this.data.alteraMensagem(color);



  }


  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.data.actualMensagem.subscribe(mensagem => this.DarkTheme = mensagem)


  }

}
```

**And in the "header.component.html" (in here, I think that the importante part of code to this question is where I have "[style.background]=DarkTheme" and where you have "ChangeColor" , so I have:**

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-custom sticky-top" style="padding: 0;"
    [style.background]=DarkTheme>
    <div class="container" style="padding: 50;">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-center" href="#top" id="nav-icon">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="../../../assets/img/logo.svg" width="100" height="100" />
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav col-8">
          <li class="nav-item-1">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#main">AS MARAVILHAS</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">CONTACTOS</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav col-4 sim">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="ChangeColor ('red')">MODO ESCURO</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps

```html
<div *ngIf="button.clicked" 
        [style.background]=" button.clicked ? 'green' : 'transparent' "
        [style.color]=" button.clicked ? 'white' : 'black' "
        >Your text</div>
```

Comment: I edited my question so that it can help you understand better

Answer (score 1):

Have a flag that toggles a class on and off for a block. Have that class control all the sytles you want to toggle

```
<div [ngClass]="{ yourStyle: yourToggleFlag }">Content to style with yourClass<div>
<button (click)="yourToggleFlag = !yourToggleFlag">Click</button>
```

Comment: I edited my question so that it can help you understand better

Comment: If you could check my question again, and see if your asnwer is different, would be very helpfull